# Merge unallocated partition with ubuntu partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

This question has been asked multiple times, but I've tried this for three hours now and could not find a way that works for me.

I have 68 GB of unallocated space on my disc and want to merge it with my Ubuntu partition (`/dev/nvme0n1p7`). I have **dual boot Ubuntu 20.04/Windows 10**. In Gparted, it looks like this:

[image: gparted]

However, the option for resizing the partition is greyed out in Gparted. I have read a few times that I had to boot a "live version" of Ubuntu and open Gparted there. **But I don't have a CD or USB stick** etc., which have been recommended all the time. I also don't want to delete partitions or things like that.

Is there a simple way of doing this on Ubuntu or Windows?

Comment: You can't do it from a working system. There is a simple way with LiveUSB.

Comment: No, because I don't have a CD drive or an USB stick.

Comment: You are unlucky then.

Comment: I can't imagine there is no modern solution to this. Nobody uses CD's and USB sticks anymore

Comment: You need some external device. And everyone has USB sticks now ;-)

Comment: Hm ok thanks. I will wait if someone comes up with a better solution and otherwise buy an USB stick. This is all really annoying, I mean it's just unused space, why is it so difficult :/

Comment: You might be able to do it from yours Windows, but is very good chance to destroy data and even be able to boot back into Ubuntu.  A decent size SD card can also be used as a live version.  Can see this link from partitionwizard, but should not mix OS partition tools.  https://www.partitionwizard.com/resizepartition/resize-partition-ubuntu.html

Comment: Be careful of the small partition in between.  1p4 should be okay to delete, 1p5 has to be moved carefully.  Then it be easy to combine unallocated to 1p7.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use GParted without a usb stick or cd. I have this working on several systems. What you do is place the GParted iso in your esp/EFI partition and add a custom entry to grub. You need enough free space for the iso which is about 400MB from my vague memory.

The details are here:

https://gparted.org/livehd.php#live-hd-grub

I followed the instructions in the NOTE part of the grub 2.x section.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move 1p4 so the two partitions that you want to merge are one after the other. Then you will be able to resize 1p7 to expand it and take all the unallocated space.